# REST get resource by two ids

Tags: rest

I have two entities: articles and users. Users may write comment about articles, however the specified user may write only one comment about the specified article. So, comment can be identified by `article_id` and `user_id`.

The classic REST GET request for comment is: `/comment/:id`. But in my case I don't have comment_id because it is useless. I think about `/comment/:article_id/:user_id` or `/comment/:article_id!:user_id` GET requests.

What is the best practice for such cases?

Comment: so you want comments that are only for particular article by particular user ?

Comment: Yes, it will be exactly one comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't call the missing commentId 'useless', as this situation is exactly when you need it. If at all possible, you should create a surrogate primary key (with no business meaning and created automatically by your DB) in your comments table - instead of the compound key of userID + articleID.

This would allow for more flexibility when/if requirements change. Perhaps users will be allowed to post more comments or the comments need to be threaded.

If the database is unchangeable legacy, I agree with the URLs given by @Gerino

Answer (score 2):

As you said, standard form would be:
`/comment/{comment_id}`

In your case I'd probably go for:
`/user/{userId}/comment/{articleId}`
or
`/user/{userId}/article/{articleId}/comment`

Note, that this is solely based on what I've seen around, not on any formal recommendations.